# ExecuteReader Connection error when Filling the DataAdapter with DataSet

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

There is a MVC Web Application which has one module implemented with ADO.NET.
The Controller Code is below:

```
private List<CustomTabModel> GenerateReports(ReportModel oViewModel)
{
    List<CentralDbCase> Cases = AppController.Instance.Prov.Cases(a, b, c, InitiativeTypes(submissionYear), includedDataSource, namePrefix, out message);

   //other code

    return DoWork(Cases);
}       
private List<CustomTabModel> DoWork(List<CentralDbCase> Cases)
{
   //other code
}
```

When attempting to connect to SQL database, I am getting below error when two or more people connect to the application simultaneously:

**ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open.**

Below are following Business Classes, I am using for this module:
1 Provider.cs (inside BusinessLayer Folder)

```
public List<CentralDbCase> Cases(string a, int b, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> c, List<string> SelectedTypes, string includedDataSource, string NamePrefix, out string message)
        {            
            List<CentralDbCase> theList = new List<CentralDbCase>();

            string sql = (AppController.Instance.DbConnection is System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection) ? ListCaseSqlEx(a, b, c) : ListCaseSql(a, b, c);

            IDbCommand cmd = DbHelper.NewCommandForConnection(AppController.Instance.DbConnection, sql);
            IDbDataAdapter da = DbHelper.NewDataAdapterForConnection(AppController.Instance.DbConnection);
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.CaseSensitive = true;

            da.Fill(ds);  //--getting error here--

            //other line of code

            return theList;
        }
```

2 ICentralDbProvider.cs (inside BusinessLayer Folder)

```
namespace PJ.Business
{
    public interface ICentralDbProvider
    {
        List<CentralDbCase> Cases(string a, int b, List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> c, 
            List<string> SelectedTypes, string includedDataSource, string NamePrefix, out string message);

        Dictionary<string, string> ListNames(int submissionYear);

        VariableInfo[] VariableTypes { get; }

        DataTable GetDataTable(int submissionYear, string scenario, TableName tableName, string tablePrefix, string whereClause, string includedDataSource);        
    }
}
```

3 AppController.cs (inside BusinessLayer Folder)

```
namespace PJ.Business
{
    public class AppController
    {
        IDbConnection dbConnection;
        ICentralDbProvider cdbProv;

        public static AppController Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_appController == null)
                {
                    _appController = new AppController();
                }
                return _appController;
            }
        }

        public void InitConnection()
        {
            string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ABC_Connection"].ConnectionString;
            string provider = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ABC_Connection"].ProviderName;

            if (provider == EnumHelper.GetDescription(Provider.SQL))
            {
                dbConnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connString);                
            }
            else if (provider == EnumHelper.GetDescription(Provider.Oracle))
            {
                dbConnection = new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection(connString);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid Connection");
            }
        }

        public IDbConnection DbConnection
        {
            get { return dbConnection; }
            set { dbConnection = value; }
        }

        public ICentralDbProvider Prov
        {
            get { return cdbProv; }
            set { cdbProv = value; }
        }

    }
}
```

4 DbHelper.cs (inside BusinessLayer Folder)

```
namespace PJ.Business
{
    internal static class DbHelper
    {
        public static IDbCommand NewCommandForConnection(IDbConnection conn, string commandText)
        {
            IDbCommand cmd = NewCommandForConnection(conn);
            cmd.CommandText = commandText;
            return cmd;
        }

        public static IDbCommand NewCommandForConnection(IDbConnection conn)
        {
            IDbCommand cmd;
            if (conn is OracleConnection)
            {
                cmd = new OracleCommand();
            }
            else if (conn is SqlConnection)
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Incorrect Connection class currently in use.");
            }
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            return cmd;
        }

        public static IDbDataAdapter NewDataAdapterForConnection(IDbConnection conn)
        {
            IDbDataAdapter da;
            if (conn is OracleConnection)
            {
                da = new OracleDataAdapter();
            }
            else if (conn is SqlConnection)
            {
                da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Incorrect Connection class currently in use.");
            }

            return da;
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: This module is using Singelton Pattern. Kindly let me know what is wrong in my code.
Thanks in advance

EDIT: Stack Trace

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.GetOpenConnection(String method)
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ValidateConnectionForExecute(String
>   method, SqlCommand command)
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method,
>   Boolean async)
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method) System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet
>   dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords,
>   String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command,
>   CommandBehavior behavior)
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)
>   PJ.Business.Provider.Cases(string a, int b, List> c, List SelectedTypes, string includedDataSource,
>   string namePrefix, out string message)  in
>   c:\Temp\PJ.Business\Provider.cs:line 952
>   PJ.WebClient.Areas.Tool.Controllers.ReportController.GenerateReports(ReportModel
>   oViewModel) in
>   c:\Temp\PJ.WebClient\Areas\Tool\Controllers\ReportController.cs:line
>   213 at
>   PJ.WebClient.Areas.Tool.Controllers.ReportController.Index(ReportModel
>   m) in
>   c:\Temp\PJ.WebClient\Areas\Tool\Controllers\ReportController.cs:line
>   154

Comment: try Using statement for SQL connection and dispose properly.

Comment: Besides `using` statements to dispose connection object, check if the connection state is currently being open using if-condition: `if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) { ... }`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto & Thennarasan: Thankyou for the reply. Tried both the solution in "AppController.cs -- InitConnection()" method, but nothing work :(

Comment: I don't see where you use `ExecuteReader` there. Generally you need to use `DbConnection.Open`, use `ExecuteReader` to read data & then `DbConnection.Close` (and `Dispose` after closing). If you're meet multithreading issue, put `ThreadStaticAttribute` at the field handling DB connection.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto: I have added the code *dbConnection.Open();* in AppController.cs -- InitConnection() -- inside 1st if condition; and things are work fine so far. But I am confused where to close the connection in the posted code. Kindly advice where shall i put the code dbConnection.Close(); by referring to the above code.